# Why is mesh.from_pydata resulting in segmentation faults?

Tags: python, bmesh

I have vertex and face data loaded from a cube that was subdivided many times, with a total of 26138 vertices and slightly fewer faces.

I am loading the object in a script, and whenever I try to load it with `mesh.from_pydata`, I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

```
mymesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(mesh_name)
myobject = bpy.data.objects.new(mesh_name, mymesh)


bpy.context.scene.objects.link(myobject)
print('loading from pydata...')
mymesh.from_pydata(vertices,[],faces)
```

`vertices` is either a numpy array or a list object. I've tried both, and the segmentation fault occurs in both. `faces` is a standard list of tuples corresponding to vertex indices.

Here is the log from `/tmp/blender.crash.txt`

 `# Blender 2.78 (sub 0), Commit date: 2017-02-24 14:33, Hash e92f2352830
bpy.context.space_data.bookmarks_active = 0  # Property
   # backtrace
./blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x1d) [0x19aad1d]
./blender() [0x104e2e6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x354b0) [0x7f720bccf4b0]
./blender() [0x19abc88]
./blender() [0x19ab12d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba) [0x7f720d2df6ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f720bda13dd]`

Answer (score 2):

The method `from_pydata` appears to be surprisingly brittle for something in Python. Something as simple as using a vertex index number that is out of bounds (number higher or equal to the number of vertices) will result in odd results followed by a segfault shortly after (for example by going from object mode to vertex mode).

Calling `validate` should at least prevent a segfault from happening. You'll have to look for what is exactly invalid with your parameters when calling `from_pydata`):

```
my_mesh.validate()
```

**Edit:** I spent a bit of time chasing segfaults with `from_pydata` myself until I eventually found reports such as the ones below. I don't imagine the use of it without `validate` since segfaults taking the whole process down are quite annoying.

- https://developer.blender.org/T32773
- https://developer.blender.org/T50199

Comment: Speculative at best. Never had an issue. Please add some evidence to back your claim. Quite possibly the answer is within the missing detail in question. For example if a list is made of object locations `coords = [o.location for o in objects]`. Using the list after removing an object will create a reference error, since the location vector is bound to the deleted object. (linking to scene after loading mesh could also help)

Comment: A good number of answers contain a speculative element, don't they? For example each time the answer to the question may depend on hardware, OS, how blender was built, how blender was installed, and the environment in which it is running.

Otherwise the issue of calls to `from_pydata` resulting in segfaults is unfortunately all too real in my experience. Since you seem unsure about it happening I added references showing that it seems known to devs.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Agree _"speculative"_ is probably not the word I'm after. The method is built for speed, much of which will be lost if it also has to validates data. (The python code is available to peruse and uses `foreach_set`) As stated in both reports, not a bug and clearly documented. If you are unsure that you are using valid data, eg using vert index 10 in a face when there are only 10 or less verts, yep agree, would pay to validate first. (or make a wrapper etc).